# MySQL to Oracle DB Migration

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-migration

I have a task to Migrate MySQL DB to Oracle (its my requirement) i tried to Migrate using SQL developer as defined in below link.

> https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/migrating-mysql-table-using-oracle-sql-developer-15

As the DB is huge, the constraints are not copied properly from MySQL to Oracle, i need to define/alter/add constraints explicitly, which is time consuming (SQL developer migrates data 300rec/min from mysql to Oracle) & the entire procedure, views, functions is need to re write.

1. How can i ensure that data has migrated properly or not.?
2. Is this is a right approach to migrate?
3. Should i move to any tool which helps to Migrate? If yes please suggest the     tool..!!
4. Or it is the right thing to Move from MySQL to Oracle.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what version of SQL Developer did you use? for data migrations you want to do the OFFLINE moves - we then use SQL*Loader or External Tables to move the data over, TREMENDOUSLY faster than what you're seeing with the online data move. Give me an example table/constraint, and i can see what's going on when it's brought over to Oracle.

Comment: SQL developer 3.2.20.09.

Comment: been a lot of updates and bug fixes since 2012 when that came out. see if you can't get version 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

No specific answer, but some genaral thoughts based on my experiences with migration.

I've found that there normally isn't one tool that does the whole migration job well, and by whole job I mean:

1. Fast
2. Handles all data types, scenarios

And that is from Oracle to Oracle!!

Last project we tried Oracle Golden Gate, and found there were issues with that.

We always end up with a hybrid approach, somethings like:

1. Extract all DDL manually and pre-create objects - there are weaknesses in the stagndard tools that confound them when extracting DDL, e.g. we found 10g expdp did not handle some quirky PLSQL well, so we resorted to extracting this ourselves.
2. Some tables work well with SQL Loader, others with GG, others (rare) with a custom extract and load process. We had over 3,500 tables and identified about 100 that worked better done as SQLLoader rather than GG. When I say better I mean with data handling and speed of migration. We created different groups of processing each group having a different method.
3. Once we have an overall hybrid scheme that works, we tune, mainly by splitting that task into parallel processes, both the export and import side.

All my migrations have been big projects where we have shifted from one Oracle system/server to another, always with the target being a newer version of OS and Oracle.

So, I would imagine that migration between non-Oracle and Oracle will through up even more challenges, and probably not as trivial as imply clicking a few buttons in SQL*Developer.

Comment: Thank you @TenG for the inputs. Its a really a headache to copy data / aligning the table structure, aligning constraints.
Is there any tool you prefer other than Golden Gate to import data ?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the expected content from the [SQL developer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/index.htm) at the Oracle website.
There are migration information available for all [Microsoft Access users](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12154/toc.htm), [MySQL users](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/toc.htm), [Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase Adaptive Server users](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12156/toc.htm).

You can also download the tutorial in forms of PDF (best for offline viewing and printing), ePub (best for most mobile devices) and Mobi (best for Amazon Kindle devices).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have successfully migrated the **MySQL database to Oracle database**. Below are detail steps:

**Operating System:** Desktop Ubuntu local and Desktop Ubuntu on amazon aws

> **Please Note:** Here I am using aws desktop ubuntu server because my mysql
>   database was pretty big. In my case there were 800 tables, 200 views,
>   procedures, triggers, and functions. The total size of the database was almost
>   20GB. In case of small database I would recommend to use local ubuntu server.

**Tools Used:** SQL Developer, VNCServer, Remote Desktop Client, JAVA 8, Third Party MySql JDBC Driver

**1. Setup ec2 ubuntu desktop server :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljvgwmJCUjw

**2. Install SQL Developer on #1**

- Download the SQL Developer package from this link :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
- Accept the license agreement and download "Other Platforms" for ubuntu.
- Install the SQL developer package as the following.

> sudo apt-get install sqldeveloper-package debhelper openjdk-7-jdk
>   openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin

- Now all that you need to do is to run the command (you might have a
  different version)

> make-sqldeveloper-package sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre.zip

This will generate a debian package that you can use to install SQL developer.

- Now install the resulting .deb package using the command (Your deb
  might have a different version too)

> sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.1.3.20.78+0.2.4-1_all.deb

- In my case, I have used java 8.

**3. Once you have done with your SQL developer installation on your newly    created ec2 instance with VNCServer then all you need to do is to    connect to that ec2 instance with the Remote Desktop Client by default available in your ubuntu local machine.**

- Use IP:1 with user/pass setup for VNCServer in #1
  [image]
- You can see the remote ec2 ubuntu desktop server. You have to grab the keyboard inputs from the Remote Desktop tool if you want to tab inside the remote server.
- Once you get connected with the remote client, open SQL Developer from the terminal or from the explorer.

> sqldeveloper

- Follow the migration steps provided by Oracle corporation:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html

> **Please Note:** While following the migration steps provided by the
>   oracle they will ask for the destination database connection i.e. oracle
>   database connection. This is not the database where your MySQL
>   database will be migrated. Instead, this database connection will
>   be used for the migration process. **Your database connection user
>   must have user and database create privileges.** Once your connection
>   have user create privilege, then migration process automatically create
>   the corresponding database user in Oracle database[if you have mysql_test_db in MySQL
>   database, same mysql_test_db will be created in Oracle db too].

Answer (score 0):

I recently used sqline's tool http://www.sqlines.com/cmd to convert a dump from mysql in the form of an .sql script to an (almost) Oracle-compatible sql script.

```
sqlines31113\sqlines.exe -s=mysql -t=oracle "-in=$infile"
```

I just had to (semi-manually) fix some things in the output and then I could run it on my oracle database.